# Use python list in Xpath (selenium)

Tags: python, list, xpath

I have a Python List and I would like to use/access these list items in my Xpath. Pls see following code

```
get_all_ids = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//li[contains(@class,"cartile")]')
all_ids = []
for ids in get_all_ids:
    all_ids.append(ids.get_attribute('id'))

['142f5222066e371e0b67382f3255011c', '0f7a5a16066f744b1647275a52384b6c', '0b0c6359523a6c4e7e07735b5d73143b', '7b781e614e3a1f314b34481b62666970', '1b243a346a281a592235112b5512647a', '3b3847693e210d1a363d146057493e54', '734f375a3a396b6c2e613e631c294868', '3b36707a0c215e596f783f200008456a', '68325f152b693a166d1816451178154f', '2d6f2821237806694f75390232626404', '273a391c315d312534291c6a16791336', '557d77524226081409532a2f18113a31', '364e4c5e4b18640f773e7e704a06182c', '0a4e34536d71796f123f5f44611a4849']

driver.find_element('//li[@id="'+ all_ids[0] +'"]//p[text()="Book this vehicle"]').click()
```

I am getting this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
```

I would like to use my list and enter it in my Xpath to click some specific items on that website. How can I use a python list in my Xpath expression?

Comment: Did you print the output of `'//li[@id="'+ all_ids[0] +'"]//p[text()="Book this vehicle"]'`?

Comment: Yes same error, invalid locator.

Comment: No, I meant `print('//li[@id="'+ all_ids[0] +'"]//p[text()="Book this vehicle"]')`. Does it looks like an expected XPath?

Comment: @JaSON   ok yes, this is the output //li[@id="142f5222066e371e0b67382f3255011c"]//p[text()="Book this vehicle"]   I have this ID in my python list, i added the list in my original post

Comment: You missed locator type. Try `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@id="'+ all_ids[0] +'"]//p[text()="Book this vehicle"]')`. Also I'd recomment to use more Pythonic way to insert string: `'//li[@id="{0}"]//p[text()="Book this vehicle"]'.format(all_ids[0])`

Comment: @JaSON thats it, thx a lot. What a stupid mistake